# sharepoint social tagging only shows tags that a user entered on mynewsfeed page

Tags: sharepoint-2010, mysite

I have a mysites application running.  I added colleagues between users.  I expect to be able to go to a different users tags and notes area and see their tags and notes.  I also expect that I can go to my newsfeed and see my colleagues tags and notes.

If I am logged in as an admin account, I can see another users tags and notes.  If I am not logged in as an admin account, I can see if they tagged the page myNewsfeed, but no other tags on other site collections.  I can see the tag in the tag cloud, but not in the Activities area.

It appears to be a permissions issue, but I am not sure where the permissions are lacking.

Comment: how did you add social elements in AAM? We have same issue the social elements are added in local url. I need to add them into the AAM url.

Answer (score 2):

its a mixture of permission issue as well aam. Please check in your database of what URLs are actually being stored in the social database. we had this issue and our sharepoint consultant noticed that they social elements were being stored under the local url, and once added in aam and the permissions to view pages/content with another amm. it just worked as you described.